# Can't See Game Car Image

Tags: python, pygame

I'm in the early stages of trying to build a simple game right now and I've checked my code over and over and can't seem to find the issue, in addition I'm really not good at coding but I'm trying to learn. In my program I should be able to see a race car image that I made myself in paint but all I see is a white screen :( please help

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

display_width= 900
display_height=600
black= (0,0,0)
white= (255,255,255)
red= (255,0,0)


gameDisplay= pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Race Car')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
carImg = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Zack\'s PC/Pictures/gameimages/racecarimage.png')
def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y))


x = (display_height * 0.45)
y = (display_width * 0.8)

crashed = False

while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True



    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    car(x, y)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: How big did you make the image in paint, its possibly too big for the screen, try adding `carImg = pygame.transform.scale(carImg,(100,100))` underneath where you get the image to resize it

Comment: @TheBigKahuna I don't understand where you're saying I should put this, I fixed my code from the person below but now the image is still too big.

Comment: put it on the line below `carImg = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Zack\'s PC/Pictures/gameimages/racecarimage.png')`. but for the size, 100x100 was a guess, instead of that, you can put `(carImg.get_width()//2,carImg,get_height()//2)` to half the size, if its still too big, half it again with `//4`

Comment: @TheBigKahuna that did the trick thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the x and y co-ordinates set incorrectly. You are using height with the x and width with the y and it should be the other way around. You have:

```
x = (display_height * 0.45)
y = (display_width * 0.8)
```

It should be:

```
y = (display_height * 0.45)
x = (display_width * 0.8)
```

Comment: Thank you that made it work but now the image is too big how could I make the image shrink down to a reasonable size?